# How to do analysis of architecture in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

If i write a model in tensorflow , maybe any CNN or ANN. I want to know how to find if something is wrong in my architecture or model. For eg. if my model is underfitting or overfitting. How to draw learning curve,validation and training curve and how to analyze them to find what should i do to improve accuracy on test data.
How to do these all things in tensorflow.Any aproach to do this in tensorflow and also tell some tips to find correct mistakes in a particular model?

Answer (score 0):

[Tensorboard](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/summaries_and_tensorboard) is probably what you're looking for. It's quite easy to setup and use, and it allows to view and analyze all the things you described visually. The default setup will plot curves for loss, accuracy, validation loss and validation accuracy, but you can also add your own custom metrics.

Comment: It is quite bit confusing. If i am a beginner to all these, can you please suggest some other resources for reading and implementing things so that i can further switch to tensorboard.Thanks in advance.